# How to stop executing bash script when there are errors? (if problem)

Tags: bash

I build my application using Maven. In my script after I build the app I startup application server. The problem is that if build is not succesfull the application server is started any way.

If I execute (with bad version that does not compile)

```
mvn compile
echo "$?"
  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "is not 0"
  else
    echo "is 0"
  fi
```

the output is

```
1
is 0
```

How to make the if return **is not 0** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you must save the content of `$?` as soon as possible, because each command run overwrite its content. In your case the `$?` in the `if` statement is the exit status of the previous `echo`, not of `mvn`.

Next, for arithmetic comparison in `bash` (and `sh`) you have to use `-ne` for *not equal*.

So I suggest:

```
mvn compile
status="$?"
echo "$status"
  if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "is not 0"
  else
    echo "is 0"
  fi
```

But it could be done more elegantly with

```
if ! mvn compile; then
    echo "is not 0"
else
    echo "is 0"
fi
```